# How do I get what's been printed by {align}?

Tags: tex-core, boxes, align

I was trying to figure out an automatic answer to [Sharing alignment between equations in two different items](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29119/575) by way of typesetting an `{align}` inside a `\vbox` and then using `\unvbox` and `\lastbox` repeatedly to get the lines of the alignment.  Alas, this does not work, as this session with `latex` shows:

```
>latex
**\relax
*\documentclass{article}\usepackage{amsmath}\begin{document}

*\setbox0=\vbox{\begin{align*} a&=b \end{align*}}

*\tracingonline=1

*\showbox0
> \box0= []

! OK.
<*> \showbox0

? 

*

*\unvbox0

*\unskip

*\setbox1=\lastbox

*\showbox1
> \box1=void

! OK.
<*> \showbox1

?
```

How can there be *nothing* in the box?  Doesn't TeX typeset something?  This is surely a mathmode thing, except that the following *does* work:

```
> tex
**\relax

*\setbox0=\vbox{$$\eqalign{a&=b}$$}

*\tracingonline=1

*\showbox0
> \box0=
\vbox(22.5+0.0)x469.75499
.\hbox(0.0+0.0)x469.75499, glue set 449.75499fil
..\hbox(0.0+0.0)x20.0
..\penalty 10000
..\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
..\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
.\penalty 10000
.\glue(\abovedisplayshortskip) 0.0 plus 3.0
.\glue(\baselineskip) 3.5
.\hbox(8.5+3.5)x26.24402, shifted 221.7555
..\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
..\glue 1.66663
..\vbox(8.5+3.5)x22.91077
...\hbox(8.5+3.5)x22.91077 []
..\glue 1.66663
.etc.

! OK.
<*> \showbox0

? 

*
```

(`\eqalign` is the TeX version of `{align}`, to some extent).  Perhaps it is more that the AMS environments do what the TikZ documentation refers to as "wicked things", but I don't see how they could trick TeX itself into thinking the box were empty.  I do notice that even in the `\eqalign` example, the innermost box of the alignment is `\hbox(8.5+3.5)x22.91077 []`; going by the dimensions `\hbox(0.0+0.0)x469.75499, glue set 449.75499fil`, this is the text (i.e. `a = b`) but the empty brackets indicate that there is nothing inside the box.  So maybe it is a mathmode thing after all and the AMS' wickedness is just hiding the surrounding material as well?

So, is there any way to unwrap an `{align}`?

Comment: In your solution to that question, you use `\intertext`. `amsmath` uses `\noalign` to solve the problem. I think it is the right way.

Comment: @Leo: There was a further question, though, about how to align not only between different `\item`s but between different paragraphs.  `\noalign` won't work for that.

Comment: If all else fails, you could always "mark" the alignment places in the PDF, saving them in the aux file, and read in the coordinates on the next TeX run.

Comment: @Andrew: I was actually considering a TikZ solution to get the coordinates, but I was curious if simply saving the lines one at a time could work.  Now I'm just puzzled by the behavior in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the main thing I was asking about is the result of a misunderstanding: if you set `\showboxdepth` large enough, then everything will be displayed as expected.  No empty boxes.

As for unwrapping an `{align}`: Presumably some combination of `\unskip` and `\unpenalty` will reveal the actual list of lines, after which `\lastbox` will work.  See my second answer to [Sharing alignment between equations in two different items](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29119/575) for the easy version of this.

Comment: You can't access the `\halign` via `\lastbox`, because `align` and `align*` add a final `\mathoff` node that you can't remove. Unwrapping the `\halign` must be done *before* math mode is closed.

Comment: @egreg: I knew there was a reason I did it the other way!

Answer (score 2):

The column width in an `align` are kept in the macro `\maxcolumn@widths` that's set after the first pass over the environment's contents: in your case

```
> \maxcolumn@widths=macro:
-> \or 5.28589pt \or 17.62488pt \or 0.0pt.
```

One can access to the values with `\ifcase`. Of course it's necessary to "export" the macro, which can be done by saying in any of the cells

```
\ifmeasuring@
  \global\let\lastmaxcolumn@width\maxcolumn@widths
\fi
```

(maybe this can be added to the code for `\end{align*}`, but I'm not sure).