# Enumerate inside align

Tags: equations, lists, align, enumerate

How can I get an `enumerate` inside an `align` environment? I want something like this:

```
%...
\begin{enumerate}
\item test123
\begin{align*}
\item x^2 & \text{ bla}\\
\item x^3 & \text{ bla2}\\
\end{align*}
\end{enumerate}
%...
```

Is that possible?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  Are you trying to number the equations, or enumerate individual `align` environments (which was just answered recently and the solution is to use `aligned`)?  Perhaps a slightly expanded [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) would clarify things.  Also, it is generally preferable to to have fully compilable examples as opposed to code snippets.

Comment: I am trying to number the equations and also number some things outside the align environment.

Comment: Note that numbering equations usually is not related to enumerated lists. For example, if there were 4 equations _before_ this enumerated list, the equation numbering would start from 5. Is this what you want when you go into `align`?

Comment: Have a look at the `\intertext` command that's part of the `amsmath` package (the same package that also defines the display-math environments `align`, `gather`, `multline`, `split`, `aligned`, and a few more). You won't be able to able to use an `enumerate`-style group in the argument of `\intertext`, but it may be what you really need.

Answer (score 13):

Apparently you can use an `align` inside an `enumerate`, as I discovered in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29120/575) to a similar question.  Just do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
 This is an align inside an enumerate.
 \begin{enumerate}
  \item First item.
  \begin{align*}
   f(x) &= x^2
  \intertext{\item Second item.}
   g(x) &= \int_0^\infty t^x x^{n - 1} \, dx
  \end{align*}
 \end{enumerate}
 After the list.
\end{document}
```

The first `\item` must be outside the alignment; all the others can be `\intertext`.

Comment: I'll confess that I'm the one who downvoted your answer, by pure accident: I meant to *upvote* your answer instead! Unfortunately, I didn't notice the mistake until just now, and now the system tells me that I can't reverse my vote. Let me inquire as to what I can do to reverse this bad mistake. Please accept my apologies.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz and Ryan: thanks for these helpful hints; I've reversed my vote! Sorry for any hassles.

Comment: How can I `\label` item inside the `\intertext` command?

Answer (score 2):

you are using the unnumbered `align*`, the reason why it makes no real sense to use it inside an `enumerate`. Maybe this helps:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item test123
\item \hfill$ x^2 \text{ bla}$ \hfill\refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)
\item \hfill$ x^3 \text{ bla2}$\hfill\refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)
\item foo
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]