# Aligning equations, splitted in an enumeration

Tags: align, enumerate

I have a problem regarding alignment for my equations. 
This dummy program shows the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item First do this
    \begin{align}
    c^2 &= a^2 + b^2
    \end{align}

    \item Then do this

    \begin{align}
    variable &= c^2
    \end{align}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

I would like the `=` to be aligned under each other, but still be able to list them inside the enumerate.

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vertical alignment of align\* in enumerate](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9394/vertical-alignment-of-align-in-enumerate)

Comment: @JPi - I'm not sure what they are trying to do, but non of them can align the `=` under each other :|

Comment: @JPi that is another topic. Still I am thinking that this is a dupe, but I can't find it at the moment.

Comment: Peter Grill's first example has the ='s vertically aligned.

Comment: @JPi no. The LHS is just of similar width and the inline math alignments (`aligned`) flushed left. If I am not mistaken, that ='s do vary in horizontal position.

Comment: @Limro If you want to get the math on the same line as your item, you may want to take [the first approach from here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54686) but you will have to write `\hphantom{biggestLHS}\mathllap{LHS}&=` on every line then.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi - not at all what I want. Look below. That solves the issue.

Comment: the same answer is given here: [Enumerate inside align](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43725/579) although that has nothing showing the output.  it would probably be good to link these two questions, with perhaps that one marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One item has to be in the `enumerate`. The rest can be wrapped into `mathtools`' `\interext` commands.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}    
\begin{enumerate}   
    \item First do this 
    \begin{align}
        c^2 &= a^2 + b^2
        \shortintertext{\item Then do this}
        \text{variable} &= c^2
        \intertext{\item Theeeeeennnnnn doooooooo thisssssss!!!}
        \text{variable} &= c^2
    \end{align}
\end{enumerate} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes - this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Limro Glad to hear that.