# How to align two or more groups of equations across \items in an enumerated environment?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, align

In the snip, we can see that two groups of equations, aligned individually on the within-group `=` symbols.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}  
\begin{document}  
\begin{enumerate}
\item
    $$\begin{aligned}
    \int x^2 \cos x \,dx
    &= x^2 \sin x - 2 \int x \sin x \,dx
    \\ &= x^2 \sin x - 2 (-x \cos x +\int \cos x \,dx)
    \\ &= x^2 \sin x - 2 (-x \cos x + \sin x \,dx + C)
    \\ &= x^2 \sin x + 2x \cos x - 2\sin x + C
    \end{aligned}$$

\item
    $$\begin{aligned}
    \int \frac{\ln x}{x^3} \,dx
    &= -\frac{1}{2} \frac{\ln x}{x^2} +
        \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1}{x^3} \,dx
    \\ &= -\frac{\ln x}{2x^2} +
        \frac{1}{2} \cdot -\frac{1}{2x^2} + C
    \\ &=  -\frac{\ln x}{2x^2} - \frac{1}{4x^2} + C
    \\ &= -\frac{1}{4x^2}(2\ln x + 1) + C
    \end{aligned}$$ 
\end{enumerate}  
\end{document}
```

How to align the two groups of equations on the same equal symbol "="?

Like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
    $$\begin{aligned}
    \int x^2 \cos x \,dx
    &= x^2 \sin x - 2 \int x \sin x \,dx
    \\ &= x^2 \sin x - 2 (-x \cos x +\int \cos x \,dx)
    \\ &= x^2 \sin x - 2 (-x \cos x + \sin x \,dx + C)
    \\ &= x^2 \sin x + 2x \cos x - 2\sin x + C
    \\
    \\
    \int \frac{\ln x}{x^3} \,dx
    &= -\frac{1}{2} \frac{\ln x}{x^2} +
        \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1}{x^3} \,dx
    \\ &= -\frac{\ln x}{2x^2} +
        \frac{1}{2} \cdot -\frac{1}{2x^2} + C
    \\ &=  -\frac{\ln x}{2x^2} - \frac{1}{4x^2} + C
    \\ &= -\frac{1}{4x^2}(2\ln x + 1) + C
    \end{aligned}$$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

In this approach, the numbers generated by `enumerate` are missing, so I'm
wondering are there better ways.

Comment: Unrelated to your question: you shouldn't use the TeX construct `$$ ... $$` for displayed equations with LaTeX. Use the LaTeX construct `\[ ... \]` instead, for a correct vertical spacing.

Comment: The use of `\intertext` looks promising, as in this answer: [Aligning equations, splitted in an enumeration](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249387)

Comment: @barbara Thank you, that's exactly what I'm looking for! I flagged myself duplicate.

Comment: @GeorgeGaarder - Your present query is *not* a duplicate of the earlier posting. The new and interesting aspect of your query is that the intermediate `\item` instructions (encased in `\intertext` or `\shortintertext` instructions) don't have any visible material associated with them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you (a) use a single `align*` environment across all items and (b) use `\intertext` instructions in which you execute `\item \phantom{x}`. (The `\phantom{x}` directive -- or something similarly invisible -- helps make LaTeX believe that there's actually some material associated with the `\item`.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{align*}
    \int x^2 \cos x \,dx
    &= x^2 \sin x - 2 \int x \sin x \,dx \\
    &= x^2 \sin x - 2 (-x \cos x +\int \cos x \,dx) \\
    &= x^2 \sin x - 2 (-x \cos x + \sin x \,dx + C) \\
    &= x^2 \sin x + 2x \cos x - 2\sin x + C \\
\intertext{\refstepcounter{enumi}\labelenumi}
    \int \frac{\ln x}{x^3} \,dx
    &= -\frac{1}{2} \frac{\ln x}{x^2} +
        \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1}{x^3} \,dx \\
    &= -\frac{\ln x}{2x^2} +
        \frac{1}{2} \cdot -\frac{1}{2x^2} + C \\
    &=  -\frac{\ln x}{2x^2} - \frac{1}{4x^2} + C \\
    &= -\frac{1}{4x^2}(2\ln x + 1) + C
\end{align*}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's sometimes nice to not have a "blank line" for the item line.  I'm not sure this is helpful to accomplish that, but thought I'd mention it: [Equations inside `enumerate` aligned on item's number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58141)

Comment: @barbarabeeton - A good suggestion! (I geared my answer to the OP's stated goal of having the item lines blank. It's good to point out other layouts.)