# How to define a variant of amslatex align environment as part of an enumerate list

Tags: align, amsmath, enumerate

I'm typesetting a book where the author uses groups of aligned equations as items of an enumerate list, like this:
[image]
together with other items of the enumerate list, which are not formulas. Would it be possible to describe a variant of the `align*` environment which, when used in an enumerate list, would be vertically aligned with number of the item?

Ideally something like this:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item\begin{align*}(T_1+T_2)(\vec{x}+\vec{y})&=T_1(\vec{x}+\vec{y})+T_2(\vec{x}+\vec{y})\\
&=T_1(\vec{x})+T_1(\vec{y})+T_2(\vec{x})+T_2(\vec{y})\\
etc.
\end{align*}
\item\begin{align*}(T_1+T_2)(\alpha\vec{x})&=etc.
\end{align*}
\item …
\item as well as other entries that are not formulas…
\end{enumerate}
```

And also, if possible, to retain horizontal alignment throughout `\item` commands? By using, for example, `\item` inside `\intertext`, or by having a special command `\interitem` that would play the role of `\item` without leaving the `align` environment?

Ideally something like this:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item\begin{align*}(T_1+T_2)(\vec{x}+\vec{y})&=T_1(\vec{x}+\vec{y})+T_2(\vec{x}+\vec{y})\\
&=T_1(\vec{x})+T_1(\vec{y})+T_2(\vec{x})+T_2(\vec{y})\\
etc.
\interitem(T_1+T_2)(\alpha\vec{x})&=etc.
\interitem …
\end{align*}
\item as well as other entries that are not formulas…
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: These don't do everything you're asking, but may be helpful: [Vertical alignment of `align*` in `enumerate`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9394) and [Equations inside `enumerate` aligned on item's number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58141)

Comment: Here's another that shows `\item` within `\shortintertext` (with `mathtools`: [Aligning equations, splitted in an enumeration](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/249377)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I've updated this answer to provide a second solution method.)

I can think of two approaches:

- You could use an `flalign*` environment and manually insert numbers on the far left to make it look like it's part of an `enumerate` environment. The advantage is that all equations will automatically be aligned on a single `=` symbol. The downside is that one isn't using a real `enumerate` environment.
- You could use a sequence of `aligned` environments, with a common width of the material to the left of the `=` symbols, achieved with the use of a bespoke `\parbox`. The advantage is that you can use all facilities of the `enumerate` environment and that you could use `\intertext` and `\shortintertext` without having to apply further positioning directives. The main disadvantage is that you need to manually choose the width of the width of the parbox; in the code below, I've set up a parameter called `\mylen` that governs the width of the parbox. Another potential disadvantage is that LaTeX doesn't allow page breaks inside `aligned` environments: this may, or may not, be an issue in practice.

The framelines in the following screenshot are drawn by the `showframe` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'flalign*' and 'aligned' environments
\usepackage{xcolor,enumitem,showframe}

% code for 2nd solution approach:
\newlength\mylen
\setlength\mylen{4.5cm} % choose a suitable value
\newcommand\mybox[1]{\parbox{\mylen}{\raggedleft$\displaystyle #1$}}

\begin{document}

%% first approach
\begin{flalign*}
\quad&\textcolor{red}{1.} & 
  (T_1+T_2)(\vec{x}+\vec{y}) &= T_1(\vec{x}+\vec{y}) + T_1(\vec{x}+\vec{y}) & {} \\
  &&&= \dots & \\
  &&&= \dots & \\
  &&&= (T_1+T_2)(\vec{x})+(T_1+T_2)(\vec{y})\,. & \\[0.75\baselineskip]
&\textcolor{red}{2.} & 
  (T_1+T_2)(\alpha\vec{x}) &= \dots & {} \\
  &&&= \dots & \\
  &&&= \dots & \\
  &&&= \alpha(T_1+T_2)(\vec{x}))\,. & \\[0.75\baselineskip]
&\textcolor{red}{3.} & 
  (kT_1)(\vec{x}+\vec{y}) &= \dots & {} \\
  &&&= \dots & \\
  &&&= \dots & \\
  &&&= (kT_1)(\vec{x})+(kT_1)(\vec{y})\,. 
\end{flalign*}

\hrule

%% second approach
\begin{enumerate}[label=\color{red}\arabic*.]
\item
$\begin{aligned}[t]
 \mybox{(T_1+T_2)(\vec{x}+\vec{y})} 
    &= T_1(\vec{x}+\vec{y}) + T_1(\vec{x}+\vec{y})  \\
    &= \dots \\
    &= \dots \\
    &= (T_1+T_2)(\vec{x})+(T_1+T_2)(\vec{y})\,. 
 \end{aligned}$
\item
$\begin{aligned}[t]
 \mybox{(T_1+T_2)(\alpha\vec{x})} 
    &= \dots  \\
    &= \dots \\
    &= \dots \\
    &= \alpha(T_1+T_2)(\vec{x}))\,. 
 \end{aligned}$
\item
$\begin{aligned}[t]
 \mybox{(kT_1)(\vec{x}+\vec{y})} 
    &= \dots \\
    &= \dots \\
    &= \dots \\
    &= (kT_1)(\vec{x})+(kT_1)(\vec{y})\,. 
 \end{aligned}$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```