# Collectively aligning multiple align environments

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, amsmath, align

I am using `amsmath`, and I want to be able to break a mathematical derivation into multiple `align` environments while maintaining their collective alignment.  In particular, I would like to horizontally align an entire derivation as though it were one `align` environment for the purposes of visual flow, so that when the derivation continues in the next `align`, the eye can easily follow from where it left off, despite **arbitrary explanatory text at any point** in the middle.

As far as I'm aware, aligning `align` environments in this fashion is not directly possible.  Is there a **simple modification** that can be made or **a straightforward package** that can be used to effectively "link" multiple `align` environments into one?

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

This alternate derivation of the quadratic formula proceeds by first multiplying the equation by $4a$, rearranging, and adding $b^2$ to both sides:
\begin{align}
    ax^2 + bx + c &= 0 \\
    4 a^2 x^2 + 4abx + 4ac &= 0 \\
    4 a^2 x^2 + 4abx &= -4ac \\
    4 a^2 x^2 + 4abx + b^2 &= b^2 - 4ac
\end{align}

Then, having completed the square on the left-hand-side, factor it, take the square root, and solve for $x$:
\begin{align}
    (2ax + b)^2 &= b^2 - 4ac \\
    2ax + b &= \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \\
    2ax &= -b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \\
    x &= \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

## Output

[image: MWE and Desired Effect]

Comment: See [How can I break an `align` environment for a paragraph?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9577/5764)

Comment: @Werner Thanks. Using `\intertext{}` for explanatory text seems close to what I'm looking for, but what if I need a paragraph break somewhere in there?

Comment: @TimParenti Than you have to ask yourself if those equations are still related enough should they even be aligned across paragraphs. Instead of `\par` or a blank line you could use the (potentially dangerous) macro `\endgraf`: [When is it better to use `\par` than `\endgraf`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96865)

Comment: This question shows other options as well: [Alignment of equals sign in multiple align environments](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11855)

Comment: i think this one may have an answer you can use: [Adding multiple paragraphs between aligned equations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59768/579)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tabbing environment.  This way you set up the desired spacing and then you can reuse it so they align down the page.

So if I wanted, the spacing below:

```
\begin{tabbing} \hspace{2cm} \= \hspace{.5cm} \= \hspace{3cm} \= \kill
Your equations here separated by \> \> and math delimiters for the math \\
\(x\) \> \(=\) \> \(6x\)\\
....
\end{tabbing}
```

If I invoke this later, it will align with the previous tabbing. If you want to center the equations, add \hspace{xcm} \= where x is the desired cms to center the line.

Someone taught me this on one of my posts:

If you want numbering in the tabbing environment, use `\tagthisline` and insert this into your preamble:

```
% line numbering for tabbing                                                         
\newcommand{\tagthisaux}{%                                                           
  \refstepcounter{equation}%                                                         
  (\theequation)%                                                                    
}
\newcommand{\tagthisline}{\`\tagthisaux}
```

Your code with exact spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

This alternate derivation of the quadratic formula proceeds by first multiplying
the equation by $4a$, rearranging, and adding $b^2$ to both sides:
\begin{tabbing} \hspace{3cm} \= \hspace{3cm} \= \hspace{.5cm} \= \hspace{3cm} \=
\kill
\> \(ax^2 + bx + c\) \> \(=\) \> \(0\) \\
\> \(4 a^2 x^2 + 4abx + 4ac\) \> \(=\) \> \(0\) \\
\> \(4 a^2 x^2 + 4abx \) \> \(=\) \> \(-4ac\) \\
\> \(4 a^2 x^2 + 4abx + b^2\) \> \(=\) \> \(b^2 - 4ac\)
\end{tabbing}
Then, having completed the square on the left-hand-side, factor it, take the
square root, and solve for $x$:
\begin{tabbing} \hspace{4.5cm} \= \hspace{1.5cm} \= \hspace{.5cm} \=
\hspace{1cm} \= \kill
\> \((2ax + b)^2\) \> \(=\) \> \(b^2 - 4ac\) \\
\> \(2ax + b\) \> \(=\) \> \(\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}\) \\
\> \(2ax\) \> \(=\) \> \(-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}\) \\
\> \(x\) \> \(=\) \> \(\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\)
\end{tabbing}

\end{document}
```

As you can see you just need the first two to add up to the same value which is 6 then they align at the `=`

[image]

Code with `\tagthisline` command:

[image]

If you want to increase the space between the lines, you can add `[.3cm]` after each `\\`.  Also, you can use `\displaystyle` in the delimiters to get the `displaymath` appearance.

Code with `\displaysytle` and `[.3cm]` after `\\`

[image]

Comment: Breaking the equations into multiple equations to tabularize them like this seems like a bit of an abuse of the `tabbing` environment, something one Should Not Do. Since I'm curious, though, is there a way to right-align a tab stop within `tabbing` to achieve proper alignment of the left-hand-side?

Comment: No need to delete the comments; better to preserve the history.  But adding \\` in front seems only to right-align the right-hand-side against the margin of the page, which is worse.

Comment: @TimParenti I cant figure anything fruitful out but I bet some others could.  You may need to ask a separate question on right aligning inside the tabbing environment.

Comment: just one more quibble -- the space between the equal sign and what follows it is uniformly too large.  (the same space should really be used to the left of the equal sign, though that's hardly relevant with the left alignment.  however, that space shouldn't be smaller than the space after the equal sign.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I wrote in a comment to Tim's question post that could be adjusted.  I just throw it together to show it works as he would like.

Comment: @dustin Except that it _doesn't_ work as I would like... while I can see the utility of `tabbing` in other contexts, there's a bit too much manual adjustment required for this solution to be considered "simple", I think.

Comment: @TimParenti once you familiar with it, it will be simple.  You should try asking another question on right aligning the the 2nd tabbing environment.  I would guess Werner, egreg, Qrrbrbirlbel, David Carlisle, Marco Daniel, baraba beeton, and there are many more that may have a handle on doing such adjustment.

Comment: @dustin -- no chance that i would recommend adjusting a group of equations aligned with a tabular mechanism.  yes, i could do it, but this problem is one of the reasons `amsmath` was created, and that handles it more reliably.