# global align parameters across items

Tags: environments, align

I've read questions asking about align across multiple environments, but still am stumped about how I might address this situation.

The following code:

```
\section*{Solutions to Practice Problems}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Write down the meaning of the Commutative, Associative and Distributive properties.  Create an example
    that shows how each one works.\\[-2em]
    \begin{align*}
    \intertext{
    \begin{description}[noitemsep, topsep=0pt]
        \item[Commutative Property:] The order in which terms appear can be changed, but the 
            result remains unchanged.
            \begin{example*} \end{example*}
    \end{description}
            }\\[-2em]
            &&& \text{(Addition)}   &   1,000 + x \ &= \ x + 1,000 &&&\\
            &&& \text{(Multiplication)}  &  ab \ &= \ ba &&&
    \intertext{
    \begin{description}[noitemsep, topsep=0pt]
        \item[Associative Property:] The order in which terms are \emph{grouped together} can be changed, 
            but the result remains unchanged.
            \begin{example*} \end{example*}
    \end{description}
            }\\[-2em]
            &&& \text{(Addition)}   &       (1,000 + 500) + y \ &= \ 1,000 + (500 + y) &&& \\
            &&& \text{(Multiplication)} &   a(bc) \ &= \ (ab)c &&&
    \intertext{
    \begin{description}[noitemsep, topsep=0pt]
        \item[Distributive Property:] The product of the sums equals the sum of the products.
            \begin{example*} \end{example*}
    \end{description}
            }\\[-2em]
            &&& \text{(Numbers only)} &     3(40 - 2) \ &= \ 3 \cdot 40 - 3 \cdot 2 &&& \\
            &&& \text{(With variables)} &   5(x - 12) \ &= \ 5x - 60 &&& \\
    \end{align*}
\item Write down the meaning of the Additive and Multiplicative Identity properties.  Create an example that
    shows how each one works.
    \begin{align*}
    \intertext{
    \begin{description}[noitemsep, topsep=0pt]
        \item[Additive Identity:]  There exists a number 0 such that addition with 0 and another term leaves the 
            term unchanged.
            \begin{example*} \end{example*}
    \end{description}
            }\\[-2em]
            &&& \text{(Numbers)}    &   1,000 + 0 \ &= \ 1,000 &&&\\
            &&& \text{(Variables)}      &   x + 0  \ &= \ x &&&
    \intertext{
    \begin{description}[noitemsep, topsep=0pt]
        \item[Multiplicative Identity:] There exists a number 1 such that multiplication with 1 and another term 
            leaves the term unchanged.
            \begin{example*} \end{example*}
    \end{description}
            }\\[-2em]
            &&& \text{(Numbers)}    &   12 \cdot 1 \ &= \ 12 &&& \\
            &&& \text{(Variables)}  &   x \cdot 1 \ &= \ x &&&
    \end{align*}
```

produces this result:

[image: Sample Result]

I can fudge this enough to align equations within each `item`, but not across items.  What I'm looking for is uniformity with left aligning the (Numbers) text across every item, and ideally aligning every equation at the `=` sign across items.  The closest question I found to this is [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29119/sharing-alignment-between-equations-in-two-different-items).  I am looking for only a slight modification to what I have here, if possible.

If not, then are there ways to set "global" align parameters throughout a document that can be across multiple align environments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For code readability you may be better off to set the content using a specially-formed `array`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage{amsmath,array,enumitem}
\newlength{\LHS}
\newlength{\RHS}
\newenvironment{bigalign}
  {\[% http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/5764
     %\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}% Stretch array vertically
     \begin{array}{p{7em}>{\raggedleft$}p{\LHS}<{$}@{}>{${}}p{\RHS}<{$}}}
  {\end{array}\]}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \settowidth{\LHS}{$(1\,000 + 500) + y$}% Longest left-hand side
  \settowidth{\RHS}{${}= 1\,000 + (500 + y)$}% Longest right-hand side
  \item Write down the meaning of the Commutative, Associative and Distributive properties.  Create an example
    that shows how each one works.

    \begin{description}[noitemsep, topsep=0pt]
      \item[Commutative Property:] The order in which terms appear can be changed, but the 
        result remains unchanged.

        \textbf{Example.}
          \begin{bigalign}
            \text{(Addition)}       &         1\,000 + x &= x + 1\,000 \\
            \text{(Multiplication)} &                 ab &= ba
          \end{bigalign}

      \item[Associative Property:] The order in which terms are \emph{grouped together} can be changed, 
        but the result remains unchanged.

        \textbf{Example.}
          \begin{bigalign}
            \text{(Addition)}       & (1\,000 + 500) + y &= 1\,000 + (500 + y) \\
            \text{(Multiplication)} &              a(bc) &= (ab)c
          \end{bigalign}

      \item[Distributive Property:] The product of the sums equals the sum of the products.

        \textbf{Example.}
          \begin{bigalign}
            \text{(Numbers only)}   &          3(40 - 2) &= 3 \cdot 40 - 3 \cdot 2 \\
            \text{(With variables)} &          5(x - 12) &= 5x - 60 \\
          \end{bigalign}

    \end{description}

  \item Write down the meaning of the Additive and Multiplicative Identity properties. Create an example that
    shows how each one works.

    \begin{description}[noitemsep, topsep=0pt]
      \item[Additive Identity:]  There exists a number 0 such that addition with 0 and another term leaves the 
        term unchanged.

        \textbf{Example.}
        \begin{bigalign}
          \text{(Numbers)}        &         1\,000 + 0 &= 1\,000 \\
          \text{(Variables)}      &              x + 0 &= x
        \end{bigalign}

      \item[Multiplicative Identity:] There exists a number 1 such that multiplication with 1 and another term 
        leaves the term unchanged.

        \textbf{Example.}
        \begin{bigalign}
          \text{(Numbers)}        &         12 \cdot 1 &= 12 \\
          \text{(Variables)}      &          x \cdot 1 &= x
        \end{bigalign}

    \end{description}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The `array` (hidden inside `bigalign`) uses a fixed-width columns for each of the components. The first column is the left-most notation. I chose `7em` since it provided a nice gap between the notation and the other content. The second column is also a fixed-width column, just like the third, but measured to the widest element across the alignments (the `\settowidth` commands). On the left-hand side, the widest element is `(1\,000 + 500) + y`, while the widest element on the right-hand side is `= 1\,000 + (500 + y)`.

You may want to increase `\arraystretch` to suit your needs. I've kept it at 1 for the example.

Comment: Thank you this is perfect! Incidentally, I was using 'array' at first, which had much better vertical spacing, but then ran across alignment problems between items. Thank you so much again for the clarification.