# align for subequations

Tags: align, subequations

The output with the code is all wrong. How can I get it to start "X" centimeters from the left margin?

```
\documentclass[11,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref,parskip}
\usepackage{booktabs,multicol,multirow,tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\title{TEST}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\maketitle    

The third term can be expanded as follows:
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
-E[2P_hL_hQ(P_h-\bar{P})]\\
&=-2QE[(P_h-\bar{P}+\bar{P})(L_h-\bar{L}+\bar{L})(P_h-\bar{P})]\\
&=-2QE(P_h-\bar{P})^2(L_h-\bar{L})\nonumber\\
&\qquad -2QE(P_h-\bar{P})^2\bar{L}\nonumber\\
&\qquad -2QE\bar{P}(P_h-\bar{P})(L_h-\bar{L})\nonumber\\
&\qquad -2QE\bar{P}\bar{L}(P_h-\bar{P})\nonumber\\
\text{after tedius manipulation, can be reduced to}\\
&=-2QE(P_h-\bar{P})^2(L_h-\bar{L})\nonumber\\
&\qquad -2Q\bar{L}\sigma_{P_hL_h}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main two problems in your code are the place of the first `&` and the `\text` command in the middle of the equations. Use `\intertext{...}` for a text in the middle of aligned equations and to adjust the indentation use `\qquad`s or any other `\hspace{<length>}` as you want in combination with `\phantom`s. A final note is for the `11` option to the `\documentclass`, this should be `11pt`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref,parskip}
\usepackage{booktabs,multicol,multirow,tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\title{TEST}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}    
\begin{document}
\maketitle    

The third term can be expanded as follows:
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
&{-E}[2P_hL_hQ(P_h-\bar{P})]  \\
&\qquad =-2QE(P_h-\bar{P}+\bar{P})(L_h-\bar{L}+\bar{L})(P_h-\bar{P})\nonumber\\
&\qquad =-2QE(P_h-\bar{P})^2(L_h-\bar{L})\nonumber\\
&\qquad =-2QE(P_h-\bar{P})^2\bar{L}\nonumber\\
&\qquad \phantom{={}}-2QE\bar{P}(P_h-\bar{P})(L_h-\bar{L})\nonumber\\
&\qquad \phantom{={}}-2QE\bar{P}\bar{L}(P_h-\bar{P})\nonumber\\
\intertext{After tedius manipulation, can be reduced to}
&\qquad =-2QE(P_h-\bar{P})^2(L_h-\bar{L})\nonumber\\
&\qquad \phantom{={}}-2Q\bar{L}\sigma_{P_hL_h}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you all! All the answers work and produce results way better than what I have....I think I'll go with the last one; it's producing the exact look that I want. Thanks everyone for the help:)

Comment: Instead of saying "thank you" is better to up-vote all answer, if they are helped you :). Also I encourage you to read some text about settings of equation. For example manual for `amsmath` or `mathtools`, https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics, http://ctan.ijs.si/tex-archive/obsolete/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf (regardless that it is obsolete, it is still very informative) etc. From all this literature you can see, that your approach to write multi line equations (as well corrected in accepted answer) is unusual. Happy TeX-ing!

Comment: Zarko - done! I'm a total newbie at Latek...so there's definitely a lot to learn. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's somewhat unclear in what manner the output is *all wrong* but both the lines `-E[2P_hL_hQ(P_h-\bar{P})]\\` and `\text{after tedius manipulation, can be reduced to}\\` lack alignment points which will cause some trouble.  By adding some negative space at the front of the first line the first equality can in fact sit on a single line.  Using `\interline` as suggested in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29120/106162) to have text without disturbing the alignment either side, this seems more well suited than simply using `\text`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref,parskip}
\usepackage{booktabs,multicol,multirow,tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\title{TEST}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\maketitle    

The third term can be expanded as follows:
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
\hspace{-1em}-E[2P_hL_hQ(P_h-\bar{P})]
&=-2QE[(P_h-\bar{P}+\bar{P})(L_h-\bar{L}+\bar{L})(P_h-\bar{P})]\\
&=-2QE(P_h-\bar{P})^2(L_h-\bar{L})\nonumber\\
&\qquad -2QE(P_h-\bar{P})^2\bar{L}\nonumber\\
&\qquad -2QE\bar{P}(P_h-\bar{P})(L_h-\bar{L})\nonumber\\
&\qquad -2QE\bar{P}\bar{L}(P_h-\bar{P})
\intertext{after tedius manipulation, can be reduced to}
&=-2QE(P_h-\bar{P})^2(L_h-\bar{L})\nonumber\\
&\qquad -2Q\bar{L}\sigma_{P_hL_h}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `\intertext` instead of `\text`, so that it's not taken into account for the alignment. Since you use `mathtools`, `\shortintertext` is even better-looking here. Note you don't have to load  `amstext` if you load `amsmath`,  and you don't have to load the latter if you load `mathtools`, which is an extension of amsmath.

Also the first line should be introduced with `\MoveEqLeft`.

As there's now room for longer lines, I propose a layout with less lines as a possible variant:

```
\documentclass[11,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} %
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref,parskip}
\usepackage{booktabs,multicol,multirow,tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\title{TEST}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\maketitle

The third term can be expanded as follows:
\begin{subequations}
  \begin{align}
    \MoveEqLeft -E[2P_hL_hQ(P_h-\bar{P})]\\
      & =-2QE[(P_h-\bar{P}+\bar{P})(L_h-\bar{L}+\bar{L})(P_h-\bar{P})] \\
      & =-2QE(P_h-\bar{P})²(L_h-\bar{L})\nonumber \\
      & \qquad -2QE(P_h-\bar{P})²\bar{L}\nonumber \\
      & \qquad -2QE\bar{P}(P_h-\bar{P})(L_h-\bar{L})\nonumber \\
      & \qquad -2QE\bar{P}\bar{L}(P_h-\bar{P})\nonumber \\
    \shortintertext{after tedious manipulation, can be reduced to}
      & =-2QE(P_h-\bar{P})²(L_h-\bar{L})\nonumber \\
      & \qquad -2Q\bar{L}\sigma_{P_hL_h}
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}

The third term can be expanded as follows:
\begin{subequations}
  \begin{align}
    \MoveEqLeft -E[2P_hL_hQ(P_h-\bar{P})]\\
    &=-2QE[(P_h-\bar{P}+\bar{P})(L_h-\bar{L}+\bar{L})(P_h-\bar{P})]\\
      & =\!\begin{aligned}[t] -2QE(P_h & -\bar{P})²(L_h-\bar{L}) -2QE(P_h-\bar{P})²\bar{L} \\
    & -2QE\bar{P}(P_h-\bar{P})(L_h-\bar{L}) -2QE\bar{P}\bar{L}(P_h-\bar{P})%
    \end{aligned}\nonumber\\
    \shortintertext{after tedious manipulation, can be reduced to}
    &=-2QE(P_h-\bar{P})²(L_h-\bar{L})-2Q\bar{L}\sigma_{P_hL_h}
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

or

[image]

```
\documentclass[11,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref,parskip}

\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
\begin{document}
The third term can be expanded as follows:
\begin{subequations}
    \begin{align}
    \MoveEqLeft
-E[2P_hL_hQ(P_h-\bar{P})]       &                   \notag      \\
    &=-2QE[(P_h-\bar{P}+\bar{P})(L_h-\bar{L}+\bar{L})(P_h-\bar{P})]\\
    &=-2QE(P_h-\bar{P})^2(L_h-\bar{L})              \notag      \\
    &\qquad -2QE(P_h-\bar{P})^2\bar{L}              \notag      \\
    &\qquad -2QE\bar{P}(P_h-\bar{P})(L_h-\bar{L})   \notag      \\
    &\qquad -2QE\bar{P}\bar{L}(P_h-\bar{P})         \notag       
\intertext{after tedius manipulation, can be reduced to:} 
    &=-2QE(P_h-\bar{P})^2(L_h-\bar{L})              \notag      \\
    &\qquad -2Q\bar{L}\sigma_{P_hL_h}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\begin{subequations}
    \begin{align}
    \MoveEqLeft
-E[2P_hL_hQ(P_h-\bar{P})]       &                   \notag      \\
    & = -2QE[(P_h-\bar{P}+\bar{P})(L_h-\bar{L}+\bar{L})(P_h-\bar{P})]\\
    & = \begin{multlined}[t][0.7\textwidth]
        -2QE(P_h-\bar{P})^2(L_h-\bar{L}) - 2QE(P_h-\bar{P})^2\bar{L}    \\
        -2QE\bar{P}(P_h-\bar{P})(L_h-\bar{L}) - 2QE\bar{P}\bar{L}(P_h-\bar{P})         \end{multlined}                             \notag
\intertext{after tedius manipulation, can be reduced to:}
    &=-2QE(P_h-\bar{P})^2(L_h-\bar{L}) - 2Q\bar{L}\sigma_{P_hL_h}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I see our answers are again very close! :o)