# Alignment in enumerate

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I want to write something like:

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item $f(x)=0\quad,\quad\forall{x}\in{S_1}$
  \item $g(x)=0\quad,\quad\forall{x}\in{S_2}}$
\end{enumerate}
```

and I want each line to be aligned at the comma (between the `\quad`s). Is there any simple way to do this?

---

Because the above example was too simple, I present a part of the actual code:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item 
$X\left(V\left(\varphi\right)\right)=\left\langle {{\operatorname{grad}}_{V}}\left(\varphi\right),X\left(\varphi\right)\right\rangle\quad,\quad\forall{X}\in{TM},\varphi\in{{C}^{\infty}}\left(M,W\right)$
\item ${{\operatorname{grad}}_{V}}\left(\rho\left(g\right)u\right)=\rho\left(g\right){{\operatorname{grad}}_{V}}\left(u\right)\quad,\quad\forall{u}\in{W},g\in{G}$
\item $\left\langle{\operatorname{grad}}_{V}\left(u\right),\rho_{*}\left(X\right)u\right\rangle=0\quad\quad\quad\quad\,,\quad\forall{u}\in{W},X\in{\mathfrak{g}}$
\end{enumerate}
```

As you can see I have "manually" aligned the commata, by inserting spaces with the appropriate length. Is there a simple way to align them automatically?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Do you explicitly need them to be inside an `enumerate` environment?  If you're not familiar you should definitely take a look at what [`amsmath`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) and the likes of the `align` environment which it provides.  Possibly you want to look at [Sharing alignment between equations in two different items](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29119/106162).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two ways of achieving this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,eqparbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item $f(x) = 0, \quad \forall x \in S_1$
  \item $g(x) = 0, \quad \forall x \in S_2$

  \bigskip

  \item $f(x) = 0, \quad \forall x \in S_1$
  \item $\phantom{f(x)}\mathllap{g(x)} = 0, \quad \forall x \in S_2$

  \bigskip

  \item $\eqmakebox[lhs]{$f(x)$} = 0, \quad \forall x \in S_1$
  \item $\eqmakebox[lhs][r]{$g(x)$} = 0, \quad \forall x \in S_2$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

(1) and (2) above is your original setup. We notice that `f(x)` is wider than `g(x)`. As such, our focus will be only on moving `g(x)` to the right a smidge.

In (4) we insert a `\phantom{f(x)}` which puts us in the correct horizontal position, then insert `g(x)` in a `math` box with a `l`eft over`lap` (or `\mathllap`).

In (6) we insert both `f(x)` and `g(x)` inside an `\eqmakebox` with the same label (`lhs`). This ensures that they will take up the same space horizontally. Furthermore, we align `g(x)` to the `r` within the box.

---

Here is a more complex example using the same setup:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,amsfonts,eqparbox}

\DeclareMathOperator{\grad}{grad}

\begin{document}

% Original setup
\begin{enumerate}
  \item 
  $X\left(V\left(\varphi\right)\right)=\left\langle {{\operatorname{grad}}_{V}}\left(\varphi\right),X\left(\varphi\right)\right\rangle\quad,\quad\forall{X}\in{TM},\varphi\in{{C}^{\infty}}\left(M,W\right)$
  \item ${{\operatorname{grad}}_{V}}\left(\rho\left(g\right)u\right)=\rho\left(g\right){{\operatorname{grad}}_{V}}\left(u\right)\quad,\quad\forall{u}\in{W},g\in{G}$
  \item $\left\langle{\operatorname{grad}}_{V}\left(u\right),\rho_{*}\left(X\right)u\right\rangle=0\quad\quad\quad\quad\,,\quad\forall{u}\in{W},X\in{\mathfrak{g}}$
\end{enumerate}

\bigskip

\begin{enumerate}
  \item
  $\phantom{\grad_V(\rho(g) u) = \rho(g) \grad_V(u)}
   \mathllap{X(V(\varphi)) = \langle \grad_V(\varphi), X(\varphi) \rangle}, \quad \forall X \in TM , \varphi \in C^\infty(M,W)$

  \item
  $\grad_V(\rho(g) u) = \rho(g) \grad_V(u), \quad \forall u \in W ,g \in G $

  \item
  $\phantom{\grad_V(\rho(g) u) = \rho(g) \grad_V(u)}
   \mathllap{\langle \grad_V(u), \rho_*(X) u \rangle = 0}, \quad \forall u \in W , X \in \mathfrak{g}$
\end{enumerate}

\bigskip

\begin{enumerate}
  \item
  \eqmakebox[lhs][r]{$X(V(\varphi)) = \langle \grad_V(\varphi), X(\varphi) \rangle$}%
  $, \quad \forall X \in TM , \varphi \in C^\infty(M,W)$

  \item
  \eqmakebox[lhs]{$\grad_V(\rho(g) u) = \rho(g) \grad_V(u)$}%
  $, \quad \forall u \in W ,g \in G $

  \item
  \eqmakebox[lhs][r]{$\langle \grad_V(u), \rho_*(X) u \rangle = 0$}%
  $, \quad \forall u \in W , X \in \mathfrak{g}$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works pretty well with my simple example but when I put in the real expressions (I also used [rhs]) the result didn't look that good. Is there any way to align at the commas, without using equation boxes?

Comment: @user3257624: There are many ways. Perhaps providing something that is a bit more relevant to your use-case would also help in guiding you. Please provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that shows us what you're talking about.

Comment: I have added to my original post part of the code I want to align

Comment: @user3257624: I've added your code to show how to achieve the alignment. Note how I've simplified the code, dropping most of your `\left`...`\right` combinations.

Comment: Yeap, that works! Thank's a lot for your effort

Comment: although I aligned the equation boxes on the left and added an extra quad before the comma, in order to produce the desired result

Comment: @user3257624: True; that's how *you* like things. I was somewhat suggestive in the way *I* would like things by not using `\quad , \quad`. You understand the approach though, which is essentially what I tried to convey.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `align` environment from the `amsmath` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
   f(x)&=0\qquad\text{for all $x\in S_1$} \label{eq:f}\\
   g(x)&=0\qquad\text{for all $x\in S_2$} \label{eq:g}
\end{align}
See equations \ref{eq:f} and~\ref{eq:g}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

To have the numbers at the left margin, use the `leqno` option as a class option

```
\documentclass[leqno]{article}
```

or as a package option

```
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}
```

[image]